# Blazor service injection not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have this code in Blazor 3.0.0-preview4-19216-03 targeting a client app:

```
namespace BlazorShared.Services
{
    public interface ILogin
    {
        Task<string> Login();
    }

    public class LoginService : ILogin
    {
        private HttpClient _client;

        public LoginService(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task<string> Login()
        {
            var myclient = new HttpClient();

            var responseMessage = await myclient.GetAsync("http://www.google.es");
            var content = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine(content);

            return content;
        }
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ILogin, LoginService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.AddComponent<App>("app");
    }
}
```

and this HTML

```
@functions {
    public async Task Submit()
    {
        var str = await LoginService.Login(null, null, null);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Full Razor file: https://pastebin.com/3LbQQvk0

I have tested it and the web request never gets done and I'm  not able to show the service response in the client. I have tried debugging in chrome following the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.0)  And I see the service method is being called but the constructor of the service is not, and as I understood Blazor should inject the HttpClient. Any ideas what can be happening?  Thanks.

Comment: You didn't include the `@inject` line in your post. Add it to reassure us.

Comment: I have uploaded the full Razor code to: https://pastebin.com/3LbQQvk0

Answer (score 3):

The following is wrong even if it is not the culprit...
In the LoginService you define an HttpClient variable into which you assign an instance of HttpClient provided by DI. On the other hand, you define a new HttpClient object named myclient and use it in the Login method.

You should use the object provided by DI. You shouldn't yourself define HttpClient objects. Why ? Because Blazor configure for you the HttpClient it creates. For instance, setting the Document base URI, which enable your web app to be navigated as an SPA app.

Hope this helps...

Comment: He also should not be using the HttpClient in the constructor, should be a IHttpClientFactory, or use it in the constructor but adding the class as a Typed HttpClient

Comment: Hi, you are right, that's one of the test that I was doing. I remove myClient, and relied only in the HttpClient injection as suggeste in here https://learn-blazor.com/architecture/dependency-injection/ but still doesn't work. It doesn't look like there is support for IHttpClientFactory in Blazor.

Comment: @rekiem87, he's not using HttpClient in the constructor. See the code for yourself. As far as I know, Http Client Factory is not yet supported in Blazor client-side.

Comment: @etragu, please display all your code so we can try to solve your issue...

Comment: Hi Issac, It's basically that, Inject a service that receives an HTTPClient on the constructor, add it to the ConfigureServices, create a component where you use this service.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you like that. I need to see all you code. Use Postman or fiddler to call the url and view what you get.